# Как сделать проверку попадания в промежуток времени

Tags: c++

> В некотором цехе имеется определенное количество станков, требующих наладки. Известно время наладки каждого станка. Определить номера станков, наладка которых будет завешена точно в заданный промежуток времени (предполагается, что такие станки существуют).

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

struct time
{
    int hour;
    int min;
};
time INPUT_TIME() {
    time x;
    cout << "Hours: ";
    cin >> x.hour;
    while (x.hour > 23) {
        cout << "incorrect data(hours), try again" << endl;
        cin >> x.hour;
    }
    cout << "Mins: ";
    cin >> x.min;
    while (x.min > 59) {
        cout << "incorrect data(min), try again" << endl;
        cin >> x.min;
    }
    return x;
}
  void stanki(time a,time b) {
    const int kolvo_stan = 24;
    time begStantime[kolvo_stan];
    time endStantime[kolvo_stan];
    for (int i = 0; i < kolvo_stan; i++) {
        begStantime[i].hour = i;
        begStantime[i].min = rand() % 60;
        endStantime[i].hour = i + 1;
        endStantime[i].min = begStantime[i].min;
    }
    cout << "Numbers of machines, the adjustment of which will end in a given period of time: " << endl;
    for (int i = 0; i < kolvo_stan; i++) {
        if (begStantime[i].hour >= a.hour && begStantime[i].min >= a.min) {
            if(endStantime[i].hour <= b.hour && endStantime[i].min <= b.min) {
            cout << i + 1 << endl;
            } 
        }
    }
    cout << endl;

}
int main()
{
    time a,b;
    cout << "The beginning of the period: " << endl;
    a = INPUT_TIME();
    cout << "End: "<< endl;
    b = INPUT_TIME();
    if (a.hour > b.hour) {
        system("cls");
        cout << "incorrect data( begin > end), input new data" << endl;
        cout << "The beginning of the period: " << endl;
        a = INPUT_TIME();
        cout << "End: " << endl;
        b = INPUT_TIME();
    }
    stanki(a, b);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Сформулируйте свой вопрос

Answer (score 2):

Работа с датой и временем легко сводится к работе с обычными числами - достаточно перевести дату+время в количество часов, прошедших с какого-то события.

После такого перевода все ваши даты становятся обычными числами, интервалы дат - тоже обычные числа, и все резко становится очень просто.

Сам же  такой перевод легко написать самостоятельно (ну, пока речь лежит в пределах одной недели, дальше полезут тонкости).

В С++ для работы со временем есть `std::chrono`.

Answer (score -1):

Если нумерация станков от №1 и дальше по возрастанию, то предложу такой вариант:

```
using setting_time  = double; // наладочное время
size_t  number_of_machines; // число машин
cout << "вводим количество станков  ";
cin >> number_of_machines;
setting_time  preset_time;  // заданное допустимое время для наладки
cout << "заданное допустимое время для наладки ";
cin >> preset_time;
vector<setting_time> vt(1); // пропускаем нулевой индекс
setting_time  stm;   // наладочное время для станка
cout << "время наладки:" <<endl;
for (size_t i = 1; i <= number_of_machines; ++i) {
    cout <<"для станка  " << i <<endl;
    cin >> stm;
    vt.emplace_back(stm);
}
cout << "в заданное время можно наладить станки  №№  ";
for(int i = 1; i <= number_of_machines; ++i)
    if (vt[i] <= preset_time)
        cout  << i  <<", ";
```

Задача простая, и вариантов решений может быть много...